# sed - add text to variable

Tags: bash, sed, append

i have html code like this

```
<a href="/site/index.php/Something" title="Something">Something cool</a>, <a href="/site/index.php/Nice_Text" title="Nice Text">Nice Text</a>
some text
<a href="/site/index.php/Apple%27s_text" title="Apple's text">Apple's text</a>
```

and i need add dots (beginning) and .html's (end) to links to get this:

```
<a href="./site/index.php/Something.html" title="Something">Something cool</a>, <a href="./site/index.php/Nice_Text.html" title="Nice Text">Nice Text</a>
some text
<a href="./site/index.php/Apple%27s_text.html" title="Apple's text">Apple's text</a>
```

I was playing with sed, but i have no idea, how to work with changed urls.
Something like
look for `"/site/index.php/` and first occurrence of `"` and before that `"` put `.html` (or after variable between).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/<a \+href="\([^\"]*\)"/<a href=".\1.html"/g' my_file.html
```

This looks for anything that looks like `<a href="xxx"` and replaces the `xxx` with `.xxx.html`. It allows more than one space between `a` and `href`. To find `xxx`, it looks for any string between `"` that doesn't contains `"`. This assumes your original contains a preceding `/` as your example shows, and that the `<a href="xxx"` is all on the same line in the file (not broken between `a` and `href` for example). The `g` option will make sure it takes care of multiple `href`s on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '{gsub(/href="/,"&.");gsub(/" title/,".html&")}1' file
```